# Finding all pairs of natural number solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find all pairs of solutions $(x,p) \in \mathbb{N}^2$ where $p \in \{5,7,11,17\}$ and $\sqrt{x^2-px}$ is a natural number.

My work so far. Let $y = \sqrt{x^2-px}$. So $y^2 = x(x-p)$.

I know that $gcd(x,x-p)$ is equal to 1 or $p$. So I will consider both cases separately (as cases 1 and 2 respectively).

I have also proved the fact that if $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $mn$ is a perfect square with $gcd(m,n) = 1$, then $m$ and $n$ are both perfect squares as well.

For case 1 where $gcd(x,x-p) = 1$, I get that $x$ and $x-p$ are both perfect squares. But I'm not sure how to proceed further. And I'm not sure where to begin with case 2.

Comment: Write the equation as $p^2=(2x-p+2y)(2x-p-2y)$. Then there are no too many options for the values of the factors of the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

For the case where $p|x,(x-p)$, then $x(x-p) = p^2a(a-1)$ for some positive integer $a$ [make sure you see why]. Thus not only must $p^2a(a-1)$ be a perfect square, but so $a(a-1)$ must also be a square [make sure you see why]. As GCD$(a,a-1)$ is $1$, this implies both $a,a-1$ must each be squares. So however, you can easily see that the only 2 squares of elements in $\mathbb{Z}^{\ge 0}$ that differ by $1$ are $a-1=0$ and $a=1$.

For the case where GCD$(x,x-p)=1$, as you noted already that both $x$ and $x-p$ must be squares. However, if both $x$ and $x-p$ are squares, then writing $x=y^2$, then $y$ must be less than $p$. [Indeed: Suppose $y \ge p$. Then even $(y-1)^2$ satisfies
$(y-1)^2 =y^2-2y+1 \le y^2-2p+1 < y-p$.] That does not leave many choices for you to check, for each $p \le 17$.

Comment: Why would $(y-1)^2 < y-p$ be a contradiction?

Comment: I think I read that wrong. Why does $(y-1)^2 < y$ entail a contradiction?

Comment: If $x=y^2$ then $x-p$ must be $y^2-p$. So as $x-p$ must itself be a perfect square, it follows that $x-p$ must be $(y-d)^2$ for some positive integer $d$. But then if $y$ satisfies $y \ge p$ then $(y-d)^2$ must be strictly less than $x-p=y^2-p$. Indeed, $(y-d)^2 \le (y-1)^2$ $=y^2-2y+1$ which is itself strictly less than $y^2-p$ if $y \ge p$.